# How to decorate different http method in a single class based view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

For example, I have a class based view which allows both GET and POST method, as below,

```
class ViewOne(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ViewOne, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, both GET and POST are login_required. But what if I want only POST to be login_required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm... Is it not working?

```
class ViewOne(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't create two classes, use also [django-braces](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) ;)

```
class ViewOne(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

class ViewTwo(LoginRequiredMixin, ViewOne):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```